# Import a csv fle to mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[Screenshot with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRmrG.png)

I am trying to import a csv file containing 22000 rows into a mysql database. But after some 2000 records its showing the error "Invalid column count in CSV input on line 2369."

Comment: go to  line 2369 and check the line struc..  could be that you a separator that is  interpreted as new column

Comment: Have you followed this: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/import-export-csv-using-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Changed tag "php" to "phpmyadmin". Corrected spelling. Added image description.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be because of the line that you had shown. 
It might be because some of the names in some other lines might have a " ' " in between the names.

If you remove that everything would pass.

You might want to use text editors to edit that and remove the " ' ".

Thanks!